# PhoneGap Build 3.3.0: Permissions - none or everything?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building an app via PhoneGap, and read like 100 posts that are all about PhoneGap and permissions, but none of those solutions seems to work.

I'm not developing with CLI, but PhoneGap Build (so I only have that one single config.xml).

If I don't add any specific settings to my config.xml, it simply requests about ANYTHING. I don't need it, I just need Internet Access and Geolocation. But no matter what combination of

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

and

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

I use, it doesn't work on Android.

```
"Permissions=none" -> Only Internet Access requested
"Feature Geolocation" + "Permissions=none" -> Only Internet Access requested
"Feature Geolocation" -> Only Internet Access requested (why???)
"None of the above" -> Everything requested
```

I *could* download and edit the APK file, but that's not a solution, only a temporary workaround *at best*. With every change I would have to edit my APKs again.

Solution for this? Any code I can try so it ONLY requests Geolocation and Network. Not everything or nothing?

I've already read through basically every SO post regarding PhoneGap in this matter but they come to the same conclusions every time or work with the CLI.

(edit: the Android in question is an Android-2.3-device - while this is old, it can handle the app and should handle the permissions as well)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need permission for those preferences you will have to set them as true and then set all the other ones as false.

It's only 10-15 lines of code in your config file.